# Show that $(n+1)^{2/3} -n^{2/3} <\frac{2}{3} n^{-1/3}$ for all positive integers

Tags: binomial-theorem

> I am trying to prove 
>   $$(n+1)^{2/3} -n^{2/3} <\frac{2}{3} n^{-1/3}$$ 
>   for all positive integers.

My attempts so far have been to Taylor expand the left hand side:
$$(n+1)^{2/3} -n^{2/3}\\
=n^{2/3}\big((1+1/n)^{2/3} -1\big)\\
=n^{2/3}\left(\sum_{\alpha=0}^\infty\frac{\frac{2}{3}(\frac{2}{3}-1)\cdots(\frac{2}{3}-\alpha+1)}{\alpha!} n^\alpha-1\right)\\
=n^{2/3}\sum_{\alpha=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{2}{3}(\frac{2}{3}-1)\cdots(\frac{2}{3}-\alpha+1)}{\alpha!} n^\alpha$$

I also tried proof by induction. Assume that it's true for n=k, so that
$$(n+1)^{2/3} -n^{2/3} < \frac{2}{3}n^{-1/3}\\
n^{2/3}\big((1+1/n)^{2/3} -1\big)<\frac{2}{3} n^{-1/3}\\
(1+1/n)^{2/3} -1<\frac{2}{3} n^{-1}$$

Then I want to prove that $(n+2)^{2/3} -(n+1)^{2/3} < \frac{2}{3}(n+1)^{-1/3}$. The left hand side is:

$$(n+2)^{2/3} -(n+1)^{2/3}\\
=(n+1)^{2/3}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2/3}-1^{2/3}\right]\\
<(n+1)^{2/3}\cdot \frac{2}{3} n^{-1}\\
=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}}{n^{-1}}$$
But this is bigger than $\frac{2}{3}(n+1)^{-1/3}$, so I am stumped!

Comment: Write the required inequality in the form $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2/3}<1+\frac{2}{3n}.$$  The above ineq is true by Bernoulli's ineq.  You can also prove using Taylor's thm: $(1+x)^{2/3}=1+\frac{2}{3}x+R(x)$, and show that $R(x)<0$.

Comment: The standard Bernoulli's inequality is for integer exponents only. This, cubing, becomes $(1+1/n)^2 < (1+2/(3n))^3$ or $1+2/n+1/n^2 < 1+2/n+4/(3n^2)+8/(27n^3)$ or $1/n^2 < 4/(3n^2)+8/(27n^3)$  which is true, barely.

Comment: @martycohen  Bernoulli's Inequality has a version for every exponent, not just integer exponents.  Yes, the standard version is for integer exponents, but the version for every real exponent is also widely cited as just *Bernoulli's Inequality*.  And it is not any less true if the generalized version is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying both sides by $n^{1/3}$, expanding $(n(n+1)^2)^{1/3}$ to $(n^3+2n^2+n)^{1/3}$, and moving $n$ from the left hand side to the right hand side, which rewrites the inequality as

$$(n^3+2n^2+n)^{1/3}\lt n+{2\over3}$$

Cubing both sides (which is OK since $x^3\lt y^3\iff x\lt y$) turns the inequality to prove into

$$n^3+2n^2+n\lt n^3+2n^2+{4\over3}n+{8\over27}$$

which is obviously true.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $n^3+2n^2+n$? It is still true, but much closer.

Comment: @martycohen, yes, how foolish of me. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For $f(x) = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$, then by the Mean Value Theorem,

$(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-n^{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n} = f'(c) = \frac{2}{3}c^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ for some $c \in (n,n+1)$.

Since $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{2}{3(^3\sqrt{x})}$ is decreasing, then $c > n \implies f'(c) < f'(n) = \frac{2}{3}n^{-\frac{1}{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary way. Let $x=n^{1/3}\geq 1$ then it suffices to show that
$$(x^3+1)^{2/3} -x^2 <\frac{2}{3x}$$
that is
$$(x^3+1)^2<\left(x^2+\frac{2}{3x}\right)^3$$
or
$$x^6+2x^3+1<x^6+2x^3+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{8}{27x^3}$$
which trivially holds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to integrate,
then, for $a > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_n^{n+1} x^{-a} dx
&= \dfrac{x^{-a+1}}{-a+1}|_n^{n+1}\\
&= \dfrac{(n+1)^{-a+1}-n^{-a+1}}{-a+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\int_n^{n+1} x^{-a} dx
&\lt n^{-a}
\qquad\text{since } x^{-a} \text{ is decreasing}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $a = \frac13$.
this becomes
$n^{-1/3}
\gt  \dfrac{(n+1)^{2/3}-n^{2/3}}{2/3}
= \dfrac32((n+1)^{2/3}-n^{2/3})
$.

Note that,
since
$\int_n^{n+1} x^{-a} dx
\gt (n+1)^{-a}
$
we get
$(n+1)^{-1/3}
\lt \dfrac32((n+1)^{2/3}-n^{2/3})
$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems nobody can resist this one :)
$$\begin{align}(n+1)^{2/3}-n^{2/3}&=\left((n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}\right)\left((n+1)^{1/3}+n^{1/3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\left(n+1-n\right)\left((n+1)^{1/3}+n^{1/3}\right)}{(n+1)^{2/3}+n^{1/3}(n+1)^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}\\
&=\frac1{n^{1/3}\left(\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}}{n^{1/3}(n+1)^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}+1\right)}\\
&=\frac1{n^{1/3}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1/3}}{1+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{1/3}}+1\right)}\end{align}$$
And there you have it:
$\frac n{n+1}<1$, so $1+\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^{1/3}<2$ and
$$\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1/3}}{1+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{1/3}}+1>\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{1/3}}2+1>\frac12+1=\frac32$$
So
$$(n+1)^{2/3}-n^{2/3}<\frac1{\frac32n^{1/3}}$$